# FileNotFoundError - Could not find module, Problem installing OSMnx

Tags: python, module, osmnx

I'm a total newbie in Python and trying to install and use the OSMnx module.

as I put
`import osmnx as ox`, I got the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\  \anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy.libs\libbanded5x.UGR6EUQPIWHQH7SL62IWIXB5545VDNQZ.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

I believe I installed osmnx (not 100% sure, though), and Geopandas too.
And.. the same problem with SciPy, but not with NumPy.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook, Python 3.8.10, Windows 64bit.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: with conda! conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx

Comment: Can you document every step you did to install it and try to run it, culminating in this error? Edit your question to provide those complete details.